# d3.drag & d3.zoom not fired in chrome, but work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

Hi all and thank you for your help.

This is a extract of my app, but the problme is same.
I have two "svg", the first "svg" is a viewport and second "svg(#doc)" is a container of different elements. I would like  trigger "drag&drop" and "zoom" from any position in my viewport. And this action transform the "svg(#doc)"

With FireFox, this is worked perfectly, but is not worked in Chrome.

```js
var coreSVG = {
  viewport: {
    w: 500,
    h: 500,
  },
  doc: {
    w: 80,
    h: 80,
  },
  transform: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    s: 1,
    print: function() {
      return `translate(${this.x}, ${this.y}), scale(${this.s})`
    }
  },
}


var svg = d3.select('#canvas svg')
  //.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid slice')
  .attr('width', coreSVG.viewport.w)
  .attr('height', coreSVG.viewport.h)
  .attr('fill', 'red')
  .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
  });

var doc = svg.append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'doc')
  .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${coreSVG.doc.w} ${coreSVG.doc.h}`)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0);

doc.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('fill', 'blue')
  .attr('width', coreSVG.doc.w)
  .attr('height', coreSVG.doc.h)
  .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)

svg.call(d3.drag()
  .on('start', function() {
  console.log('start drag');
    svg.style('cursor', 'grabbing');

  })
  .on('drag', function() {
    coreSVG.transform.x = (coreSVG.transform.x += d3.event.dx);
    coreSVG.transform.y = (coreSVG.transform.y += d3.event.dy);
    doc.attr('transform', coreSVG.transform.print());
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('end drag');
    svg.style('cursor', 'default');

  })
  .filter(['touchstart'])
);

svg.call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.9, 3])
  .on('zoom', function() {
    coreSVG.transform.s = d3.event.transform.k;
    doc.attr('transform', coreSVG.transform.print());
  }));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The `transform` attribute only works on elements that are children of an `svg` element.  You are applying it to an `SVG` element.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank for your answer.

Comment: In my case, the SVG listening to events is the parent of svg(#doc) that receives the transform. `<svg><svg id="doc">...</ svg></ svg>`

Comment: In the question you marked as duplicate.
Both svg are on the same level.

Comment: @Rifton007 why should that be relevant?

Comment: @Rifton007, The question I marked as a duplicate states that putting a `transform` attribute on an `svg` element does not work.  This is what you are doing in your code.   Quick workaround would be to wrap your `rect` in a `g` and apply the `transform` to that.

Comment: This was relevant, when @Mark explained to me that transform applies only to the children of an SVG. In my case, I could not use a group because I need a new system of coordinates inside. That's why I used a second SVG. Thanks Mark for your help.